# One user getting another user mapped customer

Tags: asp.net, session

I have one application, its running fine from past 6 moths .. now I am getting one issue... Actually I am maintaining like [loginname & Customer] mapping in one table. so based upon the login, when user logs in to the website, I am displaying the customers associated to that login in one drop down list.. Now one user login is getting other user mapped customer in drop down list.. I checked the database table all is fine I am thinking about the session.. I am maintaining session in normal way i.e, Session["username"]="xyz"; like this through out my application.. its a critical issue.. can you pls give me some inputs..

Comment: What have you done to check why it is giving wrong mapping? Have you checked where you are setting it after putting a breakpoint in code what is being set?

Comment: Keep in mind that in Asp.Net, the session is not directly coupled with the logged in user. This can happen: A user logs in with account "abc". While he is logged in, something gets stored in the session. The user logs out and then logs back in with account "def". The session contains info that was stored earlier. If you need strict "one user - one session" control, you must explicitly destroy the session when the user logs out. And you must explicitly initialize the session when a user logs in.